# joined table display without duplicate

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to get data from database using `PHP` this the Sql request you'll see that I have 3 tables but in table `Milestoneevent` I have various values for column `libelle` so I want to display like this

> Id num libelle1 libelle2 libelle3 ..... sql reql request and php

```
select DISTINCT file.num,file.id as filenumber,file.numlta,milestones.id,milestones.libelle,milestoneevent.idmilestone,milestoneevent.dat,milestoneevent.idfile from file,milestones,milestoneevent where milestoneevent.idfile=FILE.num and milestoneevent.idmilestone=milestones.id

while (row=mysqlfetchassoc(

rs_result)) {
//print_r( $row ); // debug code ?>

    <tr>  
        <td><input type='checkbox' name="approve[]" id="check" value=<?php echo $row['num']?>></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['filenumber']; ?></td>  

  <td><?php echo $row['numlta']; ?></td>  
                  <td><?php echo $row['designation']; ?></td>  

  <td><?php echo $row['libelle']; ?></td>  
                  <td><?php echo $row['milestonedate']; ?></td>  



              </tr>
```

[image]

in the picture you see that a row `cqn` have multiple values for column `libelle` in different dates

## edit

As requested in comments, here is my expected output:

[image: Screenshot 2]

---

[image: Screenshot 1]

I was forced to add picture here cause in comment discussion can not add it

Comment: `GROUP BY libelle` (or the field you want to be unique) may be ?

Comment: I'm at loss to understand what you are after. Can you pls provide expected output from your sample data?

Comment: Expected data to show
49   A2006/0324 ---1  --Exemption..-1---2016-03-03-49   
50   A2006/0327 ---1  --Exemption..-1---2016-03-03-49
51   A2006/0325 ---1  --Exemption..-1---2016-03-03-49
7 A2006/0325 ---1  --   Exemption CA..-1---2016-03-03-49

thats all 
just add other libelle like Exemption letter retourned from client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), in your query:

```
select...,GROUP_CONCAT(milestones.libelle SEPARATOR ';'),..FROM....WHERE...GROUP BY milestones.id
```

Comment: THATS RETOURN JUST ONE LINE IT MUST RETOURN 4

Comment: SEE THIS SQL

select file.num,file.id,file.numlta,milestones.id,milestones.libelle,milestoneevent.idmilestone,milestoneevent.dat,milestoneevent.idfile,GROUP_CONCAT(milestones.libelle SEPARATOR ';') from file,milestones,milestoneevent where milestoneevent.idfile=FILE.num and milestoneevent.idmilestone=milestones.id

Comment: Then, do not you want to get 'libelle' in one row?

Comment: YES EXACTLY BUT IT RETOURN JUST ONE ROW NOT ALL THE ROWS

Comment: i WANT THIS Id num libelle;libelle2;libelle3 
BUT MANY TIMES
Id num libelle;libelle2;libelle3

Comment: LIKE 
Id1 num libelle;libelle2;libelle3 
Id2 num libelle;libelle2;libelle3  LIBELLE4   ...etc

Comment: we are so close from  the right results 
now its return 3 rows  but one one is duplicate  it show 50 two times
it must return 3 but no duplicate     realy thankful for you  just check again

Comment: Do you can do a results screenshot?

Comment: I can do that just when I answer my question so seee above comment

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is the error now....I don't see duplicates in screenshot. Does the query have to return 3 rows?